# Why is respond_to used in this example?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

It's been asked multiple times, but I'm still frankly confused about the utility of `respond_to`, so I'm hoping to get an explanation of it in context.

In this [**Railscast**](http://railscasts.com/episodes/350-rest-api-versioning?view=asciicast) about creating RESTful APIs, Ryan Bates puts a `respond_to :json` directive at the top of his controller:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def index
    respond_with Product.all
  end
```

However, he's already placed his routes in a block that specifies JSON as the default format:

```
  namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
    scope module: :v1, constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 1) do
      resources :products
    end
```

Furthermore, I tried putting the same directive in my controller, but was still able to serve .html responses.

So if `respond_to` doesn't set the default response format, and doesn't prevent other response formats, what purpose does it serve?

Answer (score 1):

`respond_to :html` is on ActionController::Base by default. That is why you can respond with HTML still.

The format in the routes basically say that anything requesting routes in that namespace will automatically have their 'format' parameter set to 'json', so even if the API clients don't specifically request JSON, it will be set to JSON as a default.

`respond_to :json` is just saying that `respond_with` should respond with JSON if JSON is requested.

Comment: @LoganSerman- "respond_to :json is just saying that respond_with should respond with JSON if JSON is requested." But it will respond with JSON on JSON requests anyway, even if I remove the directive. So I still don't understand the point?

Answer (score 0):

respond_to defines mime types that are rendered by default when invoking respond_with.
respond_to :json  specifies all actions in the controller respond to json

Reference: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds/ClassMethods.html

May be you have added respond_to :html in ApplicationController.That's why they are still responding to html requests